# Selecting keys in a dict array

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How would you go about selecting keys and values from a dict array in python 3.x?

Input:

```
[
  {
    "type": "update", "name":"joe"
  },
  {
    "type": "new", "name":"matthew"
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "name":"joe"
  },
  {
    "name":"matthew"
  }
]
```

Comment: What would be the criteria for selecting keys? The algorithm that maps from inputs to desired outputs, how would it decide that items keyed by `"type"` should be omitted?

Comment: The quickest way to the solution is just to remove the type keys: `for dc in mylist: del dc['type']` but I agree with zr0gravity - what is the use case here?

Comment: `[x.get('name') for x in input]`

Comment: To give a little context, I am pulling data from an API. Problem is I have to pull from two endpoints and combine the data, from that set of data I only want to select/show certain fields. 

I used the following to select keys from a regular dictionary:

`{key:value for (key,value) in dictonary.items() if key in ['name']}`

However, this doesn't work when the dict key/values are in a list/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the `'name'` keys and their values:

```
[{'name': item['name']} for item in original if 'name' in item]
```

Comment: You have to decide which teo you want.